# NetLogo: how to limit the blob size?

Tags: netlogo

I want to create a sort of feedbacks in process of harvesting my patches. In one timestep, I want to:

- select a patch harvest a patch
- decrease cost for neighboring patches
  up to certain level
- continue harvest (select) in neighbouring cells
- the maximum number of connected patches overpass certain level, move somewhere else
- add "protection" to cells neighboring the blob

Simply, the harvest of patch always decreases cost of neighbouring patches, however my connected blob can't overpass specific size (i.e. number of patches).

Here is what I've done until now - by combining different harvesting techniques (celect the firt patch, continue to harvest by blob or not..). However, I am sure there is simpliest way how to make it work?

```
globals [
  limit_harvest ]

patches-own [
  forest?
  cost
]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [
    set pcolor green
    set forest? TRUE
    set cost 20
  ]
end

to setup-turtles
  crt 1
end

to go
  if any? patches with [forest? = TRUE] [
    harvest ]
  if ticks mod 20 = 0 [
    set limit_harvest 0 ]

  tick
end

to harvest
  ask turtles [
    ifelse by_blob? = FALSE [
     ; let min_cost min-one-of patches []
      move-to one-of patches with [
         forest? = TRUE]
      set pcolor red
      set forest? FALSE
      decrease_cost
    ]
    [ print "continuous"
      ifelse limit_harvest <= 10 [   
         let min_cost min-one-of patches with [forest? = TRUE ] [cost]      
         move-to min_cost
         ;min-one-of patches with [forest? = TRUE] [distance myself]
         rt 360
         set pcolor red
         set forest? FALSE
         decrease_cost
         set limit_harvest limit_harvest + 1
     ]
      [ move-else ]
     ]
  ]
end

to move-else
  move-to one-of patches with [forest? = TRUE ]
  set pcolor yellow
  set forest? FALSE
  decrease_cost
  set limit_harvest limit_harvest + 1
  harvest2
end

to harvest2
  ifelse limit_harvest <= 10 [   
         let min_cost min-one-of patches with [forest? = TRUE ] [cost]      
         move-to min_cost
         ;min-one-of patches with [forest? = TRUE] [distance myself]
         rt 360
         set pcolor red
         set forest? FALSE
         decrease_cost
         set limit_harvest limit_harvest + 1
     ]
      [ move-else ]
end


to decrease_cost
  ask patches in-radius 1 [ 
    set cost (cost  * 0.95 )]
   ask patches in-radius 2 [ 
    set cost (cost  * 0.85 )]
   ask patches in-radius 3 [ 
    set cost (cost  * 0.75 )]
   ask patches in-radius 4 [ 
    set cost (cost  * 0.65 )]
end

to view_cost
  ask patches [
    set pcolor scale-color red cost 10 0
  ]
end
```

[image]